# Unit test summary incorrect in Visual Studio for mbunit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mbunit

When I run my mbunit tests in Visual Studio test runner (VS 2008) my tests pass but the test summary does not include the passed tests. For a test, I created a test project with a single test and this is the test summary VS returns when I run it:

Run Result: 0/1 tests passed, 0 failed, 1 skipped

But the test is shown as passed in the Test Results window in the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably create a user defect report in the [Gallio issue tracking tool](http://code.google.com/p/mb-unit/issues/list), or directly ask your question to the [development group](http://groups.google.com/group/gallio-dev?hl=en).